# I can't find 1.8.1 jar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Okay I've tried to download mods and I did everything exactly right and when the guy on youtube went into minecraft. versions then 1.8.1, it had inside the folder ' 1.8.1json and 1.8.1jar ' and when I looked in mine, it only said ' 1.8.1 and 1.8.1json ' could this be the reason I can't install mods? I have 7zip (at least I think I downloaded it right) but I don't know what to do with it and how it works. I used forge and I'm on windows 7. Please please help

Comment: I am 95% sure you have "show known extensions" turned off, and JAR files are registered with some program (likely either java or 7z). I'd give you instructions in how to turn them back on, but my Windows is German and I don't know the corresponding english terms. I suggest simply googling the phrase above along with "windows 7".

Comment: On another note, there is no forge for 1.8.1 as of yet. Generally, most mods are available for 1.7.10 at most, some are still stuck at 1.6.4. Make sure the mods you want to install are for 1.8.1 before you install them. If they are not you have to use another version of Minecraft.

Comment: When I wanted to download blue lucky blocks, I did read that it is for 1.8.1. I am also not entirely sure how the whole thing works with 7zip, I just followed the guy on YouTube. I guess I'll wait until a forge for 1.8.1 comes out and hope for the best. Thanks everyone who helped me :)

Comment: Am I mistaken or does Windows not use .jar files.

Comment: @Virusboy Windows definitely uses .jar files. All platforms, whether it be Mac, Windows or Ubuntu all use .jar for Java.

Comment: @Virusboy there is an .exe for the Minecraft Launcher on Windows, but it's basically a repacked .jar file (same for the server .exe). The game files itself are always jar files.

Answer (score 3):

You have "Hide extensions for known file types" turned on, and JAR files are registered with some program (likely either java or 7z). That means that the `1.8.1` file you see is in fact `1.8.1.jar`, but Windows just hides the `.jar` part.

Knowing this, you can right-click the file and select <kbd>Open With</kbd> > <kbd>7zip</kbd> (or any other zipping program) even though the extension is hidden.

---

To show all extensions, open any folder and click on <kbd>Organize</kbd> > <kbd>Folder and Search Options</kbd>. In the <kbd>View</kbd> tab, under advanced settings, uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types.

[image: Disabling the hide extensions option.]

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest versions of Minecraft Forge, you don't need to open up ANY `.jar` files. The only four things you need to do are:

1: Download the latest Forge installer 
2: Install Forge using the installer 
3: Load the Minecraft profile that uses Forge (this creates the `mods` folder in your Minecraft folder)
4: Drop your downloaded mods in the `mods` folder

You can then play modded Minecraft! 
P.S. If there are any special instructions with installing the mods, follow the instructions on the Minecraft Forum or download page.